# Have SpringBoot API return 200 before processing

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have an API that I do not want people to be able monitor how long the xhr request to the api is taking depending on if the account is valid or not.

The issue is if they want to harvest user ids they can spam the API over and over and would notice real IDs take much longer to return a response. The response is 200 every time and the page doesn't do anything with the response.

Is there an easy way to have a Java SpringBoot app immediately return 200 and then do the processing?

Comment: By the way, you should really be using 202 Accepted for this case.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this asynchronously. You just need to annotate your `@Controller`s method with `@Async`. This will make the method execute asynchronously, so the connection won't be blocked. The proxy return `Future`, more informations can be found in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html).

Answer (score 5):

`@Async` is the simplest way.

Add `@EnableAsync` annotation in your main class (i.e main class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation)

Add @Async to your method which you wanted to execute in sepreate thread.

**Some limitation of `@Async`**

- it must be applied to public methods only self-invocation – calling
- the async method from within the same class – won’t work

Comment: Good answer mentioning the annotation `@EnableAsync` as I was wondering why my REST call was not returning immediately (I just put the `@Async` on my method).

Answer (score 1):

While @async will come to your rescue in a condition like this. This can still be handled in a much neat way.

1. Try to intercept the request in a intercepter/filter which just would check for validity of an account and reject the in appropriate requests without it reaching the controller.
2. On the controller invoke a async method of service, do not forget to mention the core thread pool size, max thread pool size, queue length attribute, otherwise the number of threads spawned may eat up the complete resources of the VM.
3. Do not use @async annotation on a nested transactional method of repository as a @async with @transactional messes up the transactions.

Cheers!